# JMeter RegExp Extractor for embedded boundaries

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I am new to the JMeter and developing a script where response contains embedded boundaries. How should RegExp Extractor be configured to extract exact match?

Match required: NewsId (ex. 5067113067459248186)

Response is:

```html
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=5067113067459248186&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160914&Name=Title1</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4819472530157981614&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title2</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4768659181903833291&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title3</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=5361931332129647944&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title4</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4765300220508395236&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title5</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=5543950982913791726&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title6</a></li>
<li><a class="Link" href="NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4792441472864536545&SectionId=28&SectionName=FreshNews&NewsDate=20160915&Name=Title7</a></li>
```

RegExp I tried is

```
NewsId=(.+)&SectionId=28
```

But is gives whole response as matched string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right, except you want your group match to not be greedy, and stop at first match (which can be done by adding `?`):

```
NewsId=(.+?)&SectionId=28
```

Another option is to match any character, except for `&`:

```
NewsId=([^&]+)&SectionId=28
```

If your ID is always numeric, you can also specify it as

```
NewsId=([0-9]+)&SectionId=28
```

In all cases, you also need to specify

```
Template: $1$
```